# can visual studio use debug information generated by gcc?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Pretty simple question. I have an executable that was generated with -g option in gcc to output debug information into the executable? Is it possible for me to get this debug symbol information into visual studio? or do i need to download a 32 bit gdb and gdb front end if I want to debug?

alternatively perhaps there is some way to make gcc generate the data visual studio wants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the debug information formats differ - gcc generates dwarf/gdb understands drawf and Visual Studio compiler generates PDB/Visual Studio debugger understands PDB there is no easy way to switch between them (there is actually some interresting info on possible PDB support in MinGW [here](http://mingw-users.1079350.n2.nabble.com/Re-Generate-PDB-files-td5467295.html)).

Having said that, if you as well as myself and I guess lots of others prefer Visual Studio as a debugging IDE [VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/) is a great tool to run Visual Studio as an IDE for gdb. It has a trial version, but at least I have purchased the license, the features are really worth the price in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CV2PDB to convert the DWARF debugging information into MSVC-compatible debugging symbols.  I'm not sure whether it can be used with the debugger or not, but it can be used with the profiler.

Related question:
[Converting debug symbols from DWARF to PDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907093/converting-debug-symbols-from-dwarf-to-pdb)

CV2PDB Repository:
https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb