# Backtrace using GCC Win32

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, backtrace

I recently came through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693192/win32-backtrace-from-c-code) which talks about how you can a get a backtrace in windows using C.

```
void printStack( void ) {
    unsigned int   i;
     void         * stack[ 100 ];
     unsigned short frames;
     SYMBOL_INFO  * symbol;
     HANDLE         process;

     process = GetCurrentProcess();

     SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE );

     frames               = CaptureStackBackTrace( 0, 100, stack, NULL );
     symbol               = ( SYMBOL_INFO * )calloc( sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO ) + 256 * sizeof( char ), 1 );
     symbol->MaxNameLen   = 255;
     symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof( SYMBOL_INFO );

     for( i = 0; i < frames; i++ )
     {
         SymFromAddr( process, ( DWORD64 )( stack[ i ] ), 0, symbol );

         printf( "%i: %s - 0x%0X\n", frames - i - 1, symbol->Name, symbol->Address );
     }

     free( symbol );
}
```

I compiled the code `libdbghelp.lib` successfully. But problem is when I run the program it prints six frames, Three of which is empty with 0x0 address, However the first three are okay with slight difference than output of above post (Not a big deal, right?). I don't think any of function failed!

```
5:  - 0x0
4:  - 0x0
3:  - 0x0
2: BaseThreadInitThunk - 0x7570FA10
1: RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath - 0x772D7980
0: RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath - 0x772D7980
```

At first, I gave a quick google search but didn't found any solution. I came to guess that I'm missing a `pdb` file!

Now how do I get the other three symbols? Is it possible using GCC or I'll be punished for not bowing against lord Visual Studio IDE? If no, Is it possible to generate `pdb` file anyway or using `<dbghelp.h>` functions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. I suggest to copy&paste exactly the code you use. Create a [mre]. It is unclear what code from the linked question or its answers you actually use. Show the command(s) you use to build the program. In case you use the code from the accepted answer: Check the return value of `SymInitialize` and `SymFromAddr` and on error call `GetLastError` and maybe `FormatMessage`.

Comment: @Bodo Edited the post. I guess none of function failed since something is printed!

Comment: `dbghelp` can't use the debug information of `gcc`. Maybe you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29192509/1983398)?

Comment: @vectorX Instad of guessing you should check all results for error indications. That's the purpose of the return values. Your `printf` seems to print empty strings and a value 0, which apparently is not what you expect to see. If `SymFromAddr` fails it may leave the value of `symbol` unchanged or it may set it to undefined or specific values. I did not check the details. Read the documentation. BTW: You don't need the Visual Studio IDE, you could also use the command line compiler and linker, e.g. with `make`.